# How do I get Bootstrap's Javascript to work in Vue (Gridsome)?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-component

Link to my site:

https://inspiring-curran-a31177.netlify.com/

It's using Gridsome, the static site generator for Vue.

When you go down to mobile and click on the Bootstrap Hamburger menu, it won't open.

I've followed the instructions in Gridsome's docs by installing BootstrapVue: https://gridsome.org/docs/assets-css/

There are no Javascript errors in the console.

Code from /src/main.js:

```
// This is the main.js file. Import global CSS and scripts here.
// The Client API can be used here. Learn more: gridsome.org/docs/client- 
api

// Import nav
import DefaultLayout from '~/layouts/Nav.vue'
// Import footer
import Footer from '~/layouts/Footer.vue'
// Import Bootstrap
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
// Import Bootstrap CSS
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css'
// Import Bootstrap JS
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js'

export default function (Vue, { router, head, isClient }) {
  // Set default layout as a global component
  Vue.component('Layout', DefaultLayout),
  // Footer
  Vue.component('Footer', Footer)
  // Import bootstrap
  Vue.use(BootstrapVue),
  // Add google fonts
  head.link.push({
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro'
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

Let's say you're using `Bootstrap` npm module.

```
npm i -s bootstrap
```

in your Main.js file

```
import "bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

For Hamburger please find the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/24m7o9wyzy), where bootstrap menu is used

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've updated my answer above (new link and code). I've added the bootstrap-vue.min.js file, it compiles properly so it finds it, but hamburger menu still won't work

Comment: can you add the code for hamburger here? or please find the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/24m7o9wyzy), where it is working

Comment: How is it working there? In the main.js file, I don't see a mention of any bootstrap JS import.

Comment: Bootstrap JS will be imported automatically and bundle it with othet JS by webpack,

Comment: All I had to do was add the `import "bootstrap";` line and the Bootstrap Javascript magically started working.

Comment: you can't directly import bootstrap into gridsome's main.js, because it generates an error in the project build, the only thing you can do is to install bootstrap-vue for handling interactive elements like the navigation menu

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!

I had to use the navbar directly from BootstrapVue as a component, which is here - https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/navbar. Instead of using a standard bootstrap navbar, right from the main bootstrap site.

Comment: Did you encounter a situation where the navbar was collapsed even with the window in full screen?

Comment: Yes I did, but then I found out i was purging the css which was causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you install all the scripts in the HTML ?

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/@babel/polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where would I place that? Tried putting it in /src/main.js, it's throwing errors.

Comment: Try in the html

Comment: I've updated my answer above (new link and code).

I've added the bootstrap-vue.min.js file, it compiles properly so it finds it, but hamburger menu still won't work.